# Performing a chain of actions on a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, functional-programming

I need to perform chain of actions that are defined by me on the variable. For example, I have variable `a`, the chain should look like this:

```
a.someAction1(some parameters).someAction2(some parameters).someAction2(some parameters).someAction2(some parameters)
```

So here `.someAction1(some parameters)` take `a` as a first parameter and performs some actions defined in `.someAction1(some parameters)`. After `.someAction2(some parameters)` uses the result of `.someAction1(some parameters)` as a first parameter and performs some actions defined in `.someAction2(some parameters)` and so on.
The variable `a` can be any type (of course we know type of `a` before defining `someActions`). What is the best way to achieve that? Also please provide working example.

Comment: Whatever `a.someAction1` returns just has to have a method named `someAction2`. If all these methods are defined in the same class, then they all have to return a value of that class. The easiest way to do that is to have each method simply return `self`.

Comment: @chepner Can you please provide simple working example demonstrating your idea? For example `a=2`, now perform some operations on it that are defined in `someActions`.

Comment: The shown code doesn't work for arbitrary objects like e. g. `a=2`. You would have to write it differently.

Comment: You can't call an arbitrary function using this syntax; `someAction` is not an attribute of the `int` class, so `(2).someAction(...)` won't work.

Comment: If you are looking for some alternative to nested calls like `f(x, g(y, h(z, 2)))`, then something like [Coconut's](http://coconut-lang.org) pipeline might be what you are looking for: `2 |> h$(z) |> g$(y) |> f$(x)`. To be sure, Python itself doesn't have anything like this.

Comment: This works: `a=2; a.__add__(3).__mul__(4)`. You just have to know which methods are defined for the class of `a`.

Comment: @chepner at first look it seems what I need. I need to look more into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This type of chaining is useful on operations that can be applied to an object and return a new object of the same type. For example we could define an operation square on some type and return the square of the input (returning is key because the chain relies on the return values). For an example of the pattern consider this wrapper for float that has square and square root.

```
class Chainable:
      def __init__(self, val):
          self.val = val

      def square(self):
          self.val *= self.val
          return self #This is the key line here, by returning self we can make the chain

      def squareRoot(self):
          self.val = self.val**(1/2)
          return self
```

Notice now we could do Chainable(4).square().squareRoot()..... and so on since the return type will always have that operation defined.

NOTE: You don't necessarily need to return self. It just needs to be of the same type. You could also have a few types that work with each other that can use this pattern if they have interacting operations. The key is returning an instance of the result so you can directly chain the function calls.